# API - 404 BadRequest during a POST action using curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, curl

im getting an error when using POST from a rest client. I already tried searching for the answer but i failed. I'm using version 5 of rails. Btw here's my code:

controller:

```
class ResortsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    resorts = orchestrate_query(Resort.all)
    render serialize(resorts)
  end

  def show
    render serialize(resort)
  end

  def create
    resort = Resort.new(resort_params)
    if resort.save
      render serialize(resort).merge(status: :created, location: resort)
    else
      unprocessable_entity!(resort)
    end
  end

  def update
    if resort.update(resort_params)
      render serialize(resort).merge(status: :ok)
    else
      unprocessable_entity!(resort)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    resort.destroy
    render status: :no_content
  end

  private

  def resort
      @resort ||= params[:id] ? Resort.find_by!(id: params[:id]) :       Resort.new(resort_params)
  end
  alias_method :resource, :resort

  def resort_params
    params.require(:resort).permit(:name, :location, :contact_info_id)
  end

end
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :api do
    resources :resorts
  end
end
```

What i get from the Rest Client is 404 Bad Request(parameter missing or the value is empty:resort):

```
resort = Resort.new(resort_params)
```

and:

```
params.require(:resort).permit(:name, :location, :contact_info_id)
```

Comment: Can you also post the curl command? Also, 404 is not a _bad request_, it is _Not found_ request. 400 is a bad request. Can you please ensure?

Comment: Header: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, Method: POST, URL: localhost:3000/api/resorts, Body: "id=10&name=SandsBeach&location=CebuProvince&contact_info_id=323". You're right it is 400

Answer (score 0):

The sole reason of the 400 error is that the server is expecting a set of parameters in the request, which were not sent in the specified order (hence the name **Bad Request**).

On observing your code, I see that you're requiring `resort` in the line `params.require(:resort)`. That means, the request should contain a key `resort`, and `name, location, contact_info_id` need to be in the `resort` key.

There are two ways to solve it. The easier is to just remove the `.require(:resort)` from `params.require(:resort).permit(:name, :location, :contact_info_id)`.

The harder, but better, way is to supply the params as

```
resort[name]=SandsBeach&resort[location]=CebuProvince&resort[contact_info_id]=323
```

**Edit**:

Here is the JSON body you will request with if you're using `Content-Type: application/json`:

```
{
  "resort": {
    "name": "SandsBeach",
    "location": "CebuProvince",
    "contact_info_id": 323
  }
}
```

Comment: however, im wondering how should i format the body if im using application/json content type?